# Given the following piece of code, how many time the “cout” operation is executed

Tags: c++

the question!!
Justify your answer.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
 {
    cout << i;
    cout << 2 * i;
    cout << 4-1;
 }
```

the answer that I have!!!
assuming the cout for the following is 3 but since the output is long not so sure. 0031232433634835103612371438163918310203112231224313263142831530316323173431836319383204032142322443234632448325503265232754328563295833060331623326433366334683357033672337743387633978340803418234284343863448834590346923479434896349983501003511023521043531063541083551103561123571143581163591183601203611223621243631263641283651303661323671343681363691383701403711423721443731463741483751503761523771543781563791583801603811623821643831663841683851703861723871743881763891783901803911823921843931863941883951903961923971943981963991983
I'm pretty sure I'm wrong so someone pls help.

Comment: Hint:  The loop will run for 100 iterations, regardless of the content.  Also, the content that is output is a distraction.

Comment: Add an extra statement `cout << " ";` inside the loop. It will display a white space to separate the output of two consecutive iterations. This way you can count them.

Answer (score 0):

Let's run through the first interation, where `i` is 0:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
 {
    cout << i;
    cout << 2 * i;
    cout << 4-1;
 }
```

Looks like for the first iteration through the loop, the `cout` operation is executed 3 times (because there are 3 `cout` statements).

Let's go another iteration.  We have 3 more `cout` operations for a total of 6 so far.

Another iteration, another 3 more operations for a total of 9.

Looks like there are 3 `cout` operations performed for each iteration of the loop.

So to find the total, you should determine the maximum iterations of the loop, then multiply by 3.

If the owner's of the question are considering that a `cout` operation doesn't finish until the output is displayed, then that's difficult to answer.  The answer could be zero if the buffers are not flushed.  Could be one if the `cout` buffer is flushed only at the end of the program.  Or the `cout` could flush its buffer when the buffer gets full; so this depends on the size of the buffer.  Hard to answer without a clear definition of "a `cout` operation".